# Make ScrollView span the entire width of screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uiscrollview

I am trying to make the width of the scrollview span the entire screen, however the width for some reason does not span the entire screen despite using infinity.

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("Item \($0)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 200.0)
                .background(.red)
        }
    }
}
.frame(width : .infinity , height: 750)
```

[Current Scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrlG3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, SwiftUI seems to interpret the fixed size of `.infinity` as the default sizing behavior in this particular frame modifier.

To achieve what you need, use the `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)` modifier for the inner `Text` elements to make them as wide as possible, and the containers all the way up to `ScrollView` will resize accordingly, so you won't need the `.frame` modifier for the `ScrollView`:

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("Item \($0)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh and if you need the text items to still have a height of 200, use it like this: `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 200)`

Comment: You don't need `minWidth: 0` here, it is by default.

Comment: @Asperi, you're correct, good point.